# How can I perfectly mimic ActionButton style?

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar

I'm using the support Toolbar and I've added some Buttons to it that I'd like to have mimic the ActionButton style. I got pretty close using `style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"`, but the font size or style seems to be slightly off. Adding `android:textStyle="bold"` got me closer still. [image: See image]

```
<Button
        style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:id="@+id/removeButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

I've also tried `style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton"` and some others in the button which seems to change nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure this is the right way, but I kept digging and this appears correct when adding `android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu"` to my Button like so:

```
<Button
        style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu"
        android:id="@+id/removeButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Hopefully it will help someone, as  I couldn't find this anywhere. I apparently can't accept my own answer for a couple days.